# Passar campo para ordenação de array em VUE

Tags: vue.js

Estou tentando passar o nome do campo em que quero que o array seja ordenado,
quando eu coloco o nome diretamente funciona, passando o nome através da variável não, comentei as linhas da maneira que não está funcional.

```
computed: {
    list_cob_frequencia() {
        var campo_var = 'nome_campo';
        var ordem = this.ordem_campo_cobertura_frequencia[this.campo_ordenar_frequencia]
            .ordem;
        return this.json_cobertura_frequencia.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
            if (ordem == 'ASC') {
                return (a.nome_campo< b.nome_campo) ? 1 : -1
                //return (a.campo_var< b.campo_var) ? 1 : -1;                  
            } else {
                return (b.nome_campo< a.nome_campo) ? 1 : -1;
                //return (b.campo_var< a.campo_var) ? 1 : -1;
            }
        });
    }
},
```

Comment: Já tentou `a['nome_do_campo']`? ou no seu caso `a[campo_var]`?

Comment: Não havia tentado desta forma, funcionou. Obrigado!

Comment: Montei uma resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem ***2*** formas de acessar a propriedade de um objeto que pode ser por ponto ou por colchetes, no seu caso deve ser por colchetes para torna o seu código dinâmico no acesso a determinadas propriedade, ***exemplo***:

```
object.property
object["property"]
```

***Solução:***

---

```
computed: {
    list_cob_frequencia() {
        var campo_var = 'nome_campo';
        var ordem = this.ordem_campo_cobertura_frequencia[this.campo_ordenar_frequencia]
            .ordem;
        return this.json_cobertura_frequencia.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
            if (ordem == 'ASC') {
                return (a[campo_var] < b[campo_var]) ? 1 : -1                  
            } else {
                return (b[campo_var] < a[campo_var]) ? 1 : -1;
            }
        });
    }
},
```